# Place the default help command of a Discord bot in a category (Python)

Tags: python, bots, discord

When I used the default help command, it displayed all my commands categorically except for the help command which was under **No Category**. How do I add this to a cog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best solution, but you can remove the 'help' command, and re-add the 'help' command within your cog, since discord.py does not allow you to change a command's `cog_name`. The default help command is stored `commands.bot._default_help_command`.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot('.')
bot.remove_command('help')


class ACog:
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def help(self, ctx, *args: str):
        """Shows this message."""
        return await commands.bot._default_help_command(ctx, *args)


bot.add_cog(ACog())

bot.run('TKOEN')
```

Comment: I created a command and passed along the name, description, etc
`@commands.command(name='command',decription='example command')`

If I create a new help command can I use this information or would I have to embed the text separately?

Comment: The help command in my answer works the same as the default one, so if the default doesn't require you to, neither would this.

Comment: I get an error: `AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands.bot' has no attribute '_default_help_command'`

Answer (score 1):

in discord.py v2.x you can change the cog property of the help command to any existing cog.

```
client.help_command.cog=ExampleCog(client)
```

It's recommended you do this inside of the setup function of the cog.

[Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=help%20category#discord.ext.commands.HelpCommand.cog)