# Error in Discord bot: Bot has no attribute '_default_help_command'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I have a Discord bot where I am trying to include the help from the default help command in the same category as the help for other commands. When I don't do anything, the default help command displays:

> ```
> ChatNote:
>     note Adds a note to a notebook ​    
> No Category:
>     help Shows this message
> ```

Then I try this code, based on another SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170844/place-the-default-help-command-of-a-discord-bot-in-a-category-python):

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="##", case_insensitive=True, name="ChatNote")

class ChatNoteCommands(Cog, name="ChatNote"):
    @commands.command(
        help="Adds a new note to your current notebook, or the specified notebook",
        brief="Adds a note to a notebook",
        pass_context=True
    )
    async def note(self, ctx, *, text):
        note_text = text.strip()
        await ctx.channel.send("Noted: " + note_text)

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def help(self, ctx, *args):
        return await commands.bot._default_help_command(ctx, *args)

bot.remove_command("help")
bot.add_cog(ChatNoteCommands())

bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

But this code gives me the error:

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands.bot' has no attribute '_default_help_command'
```

If I swap out `_default_help_command` for the method auto-complete gives me, `DefaultHelpCommand`, I get a new error:

```
Command raised an exception: TypeError: can't pickle _asyncio.Future objects
```

It's kind of obvious what the error means, but what method name am I supposed to use, or, in general, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you trying to get help with command for example the command `##help note` to make the bot reply with the '`note`' commands description? Or are you trying to return the default help menu which shows all commands?

Comment: @LoremI. I am trying to display the default help menu with all commands, but with `help` in the same category as `note`, not in its own `No Category`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `cog` of the help_command using [`bot.help_command.cog`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.HelpCommand.cog).

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="##", case_insensitive=True, name="ChatNote")

class ChatNoteCommands(commands.Cog, name="ChatNote"):
    @commands.command(
        help="Adds a new note to your current notebook, or the specified notebook",
        brief="Adds a note to a notebook",
        pass_context=True
    )
    async def note(self, ctx, *, text):
        note_text = text.strip()
        await ctx.channel.send("Noted: " + note_text)

bot.add_cog(ChatNoteCommands())
bot.help_command.cog = bot.cogs["ChatNote"]

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thank you,, very close, but I now get the following output for `##help`:

`ChatNote
    note Adds a note to a notebook
​ChatNote:
    help Shows this message`

That is, I have 2 of the same categories, with `no_category` seeming toi get its own, duplicate category.

Comment: I've updated the code to set the `cog` of the help command to the one that is created, which should yield the desired results.